# Squid : Do not cache these destinations ( I do not want some address to be cached by squid )

Tags: proxy, cache, squid

I have a virtual proxy client and I have a squid proxy server. I would like to add some addresses to block caching for them. Either their domain or IP address:

```
www.apache.org
188.184.21.108
```

```
root@SERVER:/etc/squid # cat /etc/squid/acls/dst_nocache.acl
www.apache.org
188.184.21.108
```

I added them to the list for non-cache, but it still caches.
I check from here:

```
root@SERVER:/etc/squid # tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log
```

How can I do this, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just needed to understand more about Squid Caching Proxy Access.log.

- "TCP_" refers to requests on the HTTP port (3128)
- TCP_HIT A valid copy of the requested object was in the cache.
- TCP_MISS The requested object was not in the cache.
- TCP_REFRESH_HIT An expired copy of the requested object was in the
  cache. Squid made an If-Modified-Since request and the response was
  "Not Modified."
- TCP_REFRESH_FAIL_HIT An expired copy of the requested object was in
  the cache. Squid attempted to make an If-Modified-Since request, but
  it failed. The old (stale) object was delivered to the client.
- TCP_REFRESH_MISS An expired copy of the requested object was in the
  cache. Squid made an If-Modified-Since request and received a new,
  different object.

  TCP_CLIENT_REFRESH The client issued a request with the "no-cache"
  pragma. ("reload" - handled as MISS)

  TCP_IMS_HIT An If-Modified-Since GET request was received from the
  client. A valid copy of the object was in the cache (fresh).

  TCP_IMS_MISS An If-Modified-Since GET request was received from the
  client. The requested object was not in the cache (stale).

  TCP_SWAPFAIL The object was believed to be in the cache, but could
  not be accessed.

  TCP_DENIED Access was denied for this request.